# Strange issue with UIActionSheet title

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiactionsheet

I'm running into a weird issue where I can't seem to change the title of a `UIActionSheet`. This is how I initialize the action sheet:

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Options" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Nevermind" destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveTitle otherButtonTitles:nil];
popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[popupQuery showInView:self];
```

Everything (including the button titles) works fine, except the main action sheet title. For some reason, it always shows "title" when I run it, instead of "Options". Even more strangely, this same code used to work fine, and only broke recently, possibly with an update of the SDK or iOS.

Note that I'm also able to change the title using the following code:

```
[[[popupQuery subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setText:@"Options"];
```

If I add the above line it shows the correct title; however, I am concerned about using such a hack instead of the standard solution. Any ideas of what might be going on?

**Update:**

The following code:

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Options" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Nevermind" destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveTitle otherButtonTitles:nil];

NSLog(@"title is : %@", popupQuery.title);
[popupQuery setTitle:@"Options"];
NSLog(@"title is now : %@", popupQuery.title);
```

produces the output:

```
2014-02-20 21:48:29.862 APP[68219:907] title is : title
2014-02-20 21:48:29.862 APP[68219:907] title is now : title
```

instead of what I'd expect, i.e. "Options" both times.

Comment: Where is this code running? You are producing a UIActionSheet from within a _view_'s code? (`self` is a view????)

Comment: @matt: yes, it's running in a custom table view cell.

Comment: Okay, but you cannot produce an action sheet from a table cell. Instead of `showInView:self`, try saying `showInView:self.window.rootViewController.view`.

Comment: @matt: I tried that already, same result. I also added a debug log that shows that it is not working even before I try showing it (which works, apart from the title being wrong)

Comment: @matt You can show an action sheet from any view you want. On the iPad it will show the action sheet in the middle of the screen. On an iPhone it simply appears from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @houbysoft Is this on an iOS device or the simulator? Which version of iOS?

Comment: Could something be wrong with `destructiveTitle` that is messing things up? (Just clutching at straws now)

Comment: @rmaddy: I tried it on both the simulator (7.0 and 6.1) and an iPhone (7.0).

Comment: @matt: I just replaced with @"test", and the issue persists.

Comment: Try creating an empty project and move you’r apps code/assets there one at a time until you can reproduce the problem.  This will help you understand where the problem is coming from. (BTW I have created an empty project, copied and pasted your code and the title appears correctly for me).

Comment: @BenjaminAlbert: yes, I tried it in an empty project too and it worked as you say. However this is in a very large codebase and doing this would take a very long time, so I was going to try my luck here first...

Comment: I am betting you are using some third party code that messes with UIActionSheet thru a category or similar.

Comment: @matt: hmm that seems possible.. though I did just run a full text search for UIActionSheet, found UIActionSheet+BlocksKit.h/m, and a subclass SHKActionSheet. I deleted all of this, cleaned / rebuilt the project, yet the issue still appears.

Comment: Nevertheless I bet that's it. BlocksKit works by method swizzling.

Comment: I had this same problem and in the end it turned out to be a Taplytics library that caused this. Not sure if you use this or not... The way I found out was just going back in my history and trying different states of the code. Look for commits where you added a third party library.

Comment: And updating the Taplytics library to the latest version fixed it.